# Regex checking previous groups

Tags: regex

I am having difficulties writing a regex expression. These are my rules:
Can be between 0 and 10 numbers, separated by commas.
Each number is between 0 and 2000 inclusive.
There should be no repeated numbers in this pattern (this is the tricky part).
Here's the monster I tried:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)(,(?!\1)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}(,(?!\1|\3)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}(,(?!\1|\3|\5)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}(,(?!\1|\3|\5|\7)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}(,(?!\1|\3|\5|\7|\9)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}(,(?!\1|\3|\5|\7|\9|\11)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}(,(?!\1|\3|\5|\7|\9|\11|\13)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}(,(?!\1|\3|\5|\7|\9|\11|\13|\15)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}(,(?!\1|\3|\5|\7|\9|\11|\13|\15|\17)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,1}$
```

It seems to have issues with numbers in the low 10s in the middle of the string.

Is there a better way of solving this problem with RegEx at all?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)(?:,(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,9})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZWqjJ/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a repeating chunk of 1+ digits as a whole word
- `(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)(?:,(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,9})?` - an optional sequence of (i.e. the whole string may be empty):

  - `(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)` - a number from `0` to `2000`
  - `(?:,(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)){0,9}` - 0 to 9 occurrences of:

    - `,` -  a comma
    - `(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{3}|2000)` - a number from `0` to `2000`
- `$` - end of string.

To generate patterns for specific number ranges you may use [this online generator](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) (no affiliation on my part). The resulting regex might not be the most optimal, but it works.

Note that you may use a more readable and maintainable approach: split a string with commas, make sure there are less than 11 items, make sure they are all numbers, and then check if all of the numbers are between 0 and 2000.